# I've seen the following code in C++. Is it defined behavior?

Tags: c++

Is this code well-defined according to the C++ standard? It seems slightly hacky.

```
#include <string>
char* GetPointer(std::string& s)
{
    return &s[0];
}
```

Is that code ensured by the standard to return a pointer to the first element in the array storing the characters?

Comment: Why wouldn't it, unless s is null? You should just use char arrays instead of std::string though.

Comment: It returns a pointer to array of chars (char *). The advantage of this solution above c_str() is that you have NON const pointer.

Comment: Yes it is, but it's useless. See [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: @nosbor No, it returns a pointer-to-one-`char`, which just happens to be the start of a null-terminated C string.

Comment: Did you check the  [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)?

Comment: @wasthishelpful It's not useless at all if one wants a non-`const` `char *`, which isn't an available return type until C++17.

Comment: It is not usless. It depends which version of c++ compiler you use. ::data is NOT available in all versions.

Comment: @nosbor ...and even in those versions where `.data()` is available, it cannot (officially) return a non-`const` pointer unless using C++17 and a sufficiently up-to-date stdlib.

Comment: @underscore_d first, that string is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, and the rest what I was going to say here is said in Nicola Benes's answer below

Comment: Since C++11, it is guaranteed to be null-terminated, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data. "The returned array is null-terminated, that is, data() and c_str() perform the same function."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

> The elements of a basic_string are stored contiguously, that is, for a basic_string s, &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n for any n in [0, s.size()), or, equivalently, a pointer to s[0] can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a CharT[] array.

source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: If the strings `.size()` is `0` you are in trouble though.

Comment: No, you're not. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at. "If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned."

Comment: Hmm, seems you are right. Interresting difference from vector. Shows how assumptions about one container can bite you when talking about a different one. Today I learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the canonical way of getting a `char` pointer from `std::string`, so there's nothing wrong with it. The caller needs to be aware that the pointer becomes invalid if the string changes.

It's convenient to put stuff that "looks hacky" into a function so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom While this method works, I doubt it should be called the *canonical* one. What is canonical and what isn't is specified by the standard.

Comment: _"That's the canonical way of getting a char pointer from std::string"_ more canonical than `std::string::data()`?

Comment: @MarkRansom I pasted the wrong comment on the wrong answer and got confused. This _is_ the canonical way until C++17 adds non-`const` `data()`. Carry on :-)

Comment: @lisyarus it's canonical because it's the *only* way to get a non-const pointer, at least until C++17 as underscore_d points out. And having it a function makes it easy to change once that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code well-defined according to the C++ standard?
>
> Is that code ensured by the standard to return a pointer to the first element in the array storing the characters?

Yes and yes.

However, you must realize that the pointed array of chars is not guaranteed to be null terminated. So, you may not pass the pointer to functions that require a null terminated string - unless you set the terminator yourself.

> It seems slightly hacky.

It might seem so, but currently this is how to get non-const pointer to the internal array. C++17 will add `char* std::string::data()` to make this cleaner.

Comment: That's not a proposal anymore ;-)

Comment: Related to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506473/in-c11-and-beyond-does-stdstringoperator-do-bounds-checking) in the comments from the answer by LRIO we find 21.4.7.1 where data is defined as *A pointer p such that p + i == &operator[](i) for each i in [0,size()].*  This leads me to believe that it must be null terminated.

Comment: @NathanOliver I only see how that guarantees that the string returned by `data()` must be null terminated. I don't see the guarantee about the null being there unless `data()` (or `c_str()` or `operator[](size())`) was called.

Comment: Well it states that `&foo[n]` is valid for all `n` in `[0, size()]` and then we also have that `[size()]` returns `charT()`.  There might be a way to do this without storing the `charT()` at `[size()]` but I don't know of a way and keeping constant complexity.

Comment: @NathanOliver always allocate memory for the terminator, but only initialize it to null if one of the mentioned functions are called. Probably not most efficient, but seems to comply with standard as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe.  Hopefully it is cleared up in C++17

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to return a pointer into some memory whose location was passed into the function.
It would have been a different story if the `std::string` would have been passed by value.

Just, remember that the return-value's validity is tied to the passed object's internal buffer.